# Second Coded UI test within a group of tests executed from VS2010 hangs and makes all subsequent tests fail

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, testing, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I have a whole lot of Coded UI tests that I developed as part of our integration, system, and acceptance testing suite.

By definition each test has to start from a clean slate, and as such any given test has to drop one, two, or three of the underlying databases that the product relies on. Moreover, tests are also machine specific and as such they are data driven via XML files, giving the testers flexibility to run the tests on any machine they chose, as long as they follow the test setup procedures.

I developed configuration settings for the test executable where you can configure the database connection string, sa account, as well as run time accounts used to connect to the database. These settings reside in the app.config of the test executable.

At the beginning of each test I call a static method of an object, for example `SQLUtility` where I would drop the existing database and restore it from back up. The `SQLUtility` object uses the `Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.SMO` and ensures that it connects to SQL Server with the SA account, does the restore operation, and finally re-creates the DB logins used by the product to access the specified database(s).

The problem I am experiencing is that if I ran the tests one at a time manually, they run fine. If I run all tests in the current context, only the first one executes and the second one times out.

Can any one help me, or point me in the right direction, as to why this happens? Is it possible that because the `SQLUtility` is a static object it doesn't get unloaded properly by the Microsoft Test framework between each test?

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: Where do you define the object that executes 'SQLUtility' method? Does your first test (and each test) wait until the restore to be completed?

Comment: Yes. Each test waits until the restore has completely finished. I did some experimenting and found out that the delay has to do with the SQL Server assemblies used by the SQLUtility. Not knowing what assemblies are needed I added all of Microsoft.SQLServer.* as references. When I removed some of the unnecessary references, the tests ran very quick, but all of them broke when interacting with the UI. :( So now I am going to start over.

Comment: We had tha same issue (restoring db after test run) and solved it by calling two methods. The first (called on TestInitialize()) gets a db snapshot and the second (called on TestCleanup()) restores the db snapshot. Both methods executes sql queries provided by our Sql developer. The only reference added is the 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'. Just curious, how long it takes to restore the backup?

Comment: Well, full restore with the creation of DB logins takes about 3 seconds in debug mode. The restore uses a blank database backup, which has all tables, relationships, views, and stored procs defined. No data. The size of the backup is roughly 1 meg. The entire thing executes in a Win Srv 2008R2 VM.

I figured out why I was experiencing the issues with delays and time outs - I had added unnecessary Microsoft.SqlServer.* assemblies, some of which turned out to consume unmanaged resources internally thus introducing unnecessary latency. Once I trimmed the fat down to a minimum - I had no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the object for 'SQLUtility' method in each Test Method. Don't declare it globally. I hope this will solve you problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. I found a work around where instead of restoring the database I just delete everything from all tables and reset the primary keys to restart from default...